# Complicated VLookUp within For Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

Essentially I need to create a VLOOKUP that refers to another sheet in my workbook and grabs data from a relevant row to create the lookup value.
Column A has names of trains, B has station names. The header in columns C, F, I, L... have a day of the week. I need to apply a VLOOKUP over each column, for instance here Column C, with a dynamic number of rows that will lookup the concatenated string of Cell(A, [row VLOOKUP is being applied to]) and Cell(B,[row VLOOKUP is being applied to]) and Cell(C1).

My current code:

```
i = 3
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Worksheets("% On Time Customers").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Worksheets("% On Time Customers").Range("C3:C" & lastRow)
    lookupSunday1 = CStr(Cells(i, 1) & "/" & Cells(1, 3) & "/" & Cells(i, 2))
    cell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(lookupSunday1,'COTP'!$I:$Y,11)"
    i = i + 1
Next
```

This works for Column C kinda - there is a #NAME? error and each cell contains =VLOOKUP(@lookupSunday1,COTP!$I:%Y,11) rather than the result of the lookup which I'm not sure how to fix.

I'd rather not have to create for loops for each of the days of the week, especially because under each day of the week, there are three separate columns requiring another lookup, and that seems very time intensive. However, if that's the way to do it, then it'll work.

[spreadsheet layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRBlU.png)

Comment: `Index()` each column's info after you `Match()` once, or match once and `destination.value=source.value` if the column locations don't change using the `Match()` row.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you did not concatenate `lookupSunday1` variable in the formula equation but kept the name literally in equation which returns `#NAME` error on spreadsheet due to unknown object.

Consider following adjustment that uses `i` as iterator and qualifies all `Rows` and `Cells` reference with worksheet, facilitated by `With` block. Triple quotes needed to enclose string value in formula.

```vb
Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer

With Worksheets("% On Time Customers")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 to lastRow
        lookupSunday1 = CStr(.Cells(i, 1) & "/" & .Cells(1, 3) & "/" & .Cells(i, 2))
        .Range("C" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & lookupSunday1 & """, 'COTP'!$I:$Y, 11)"
    Next i
End With
```